# Can I understand this sentence in this way?

Tags: meaning

This is the original sentence:

> This is sapping political energy from continent-wide deals such as the Transatlantic Trade and Investment Partnership and Trans-Pacific Partnership.

Does it mean the same as this?:

> Continent-wide deals such as the Transatlantic Trade and Investment Partnership and Trans-Pacific Partnership are sapping political energy."

source: http://www.businessinsider.com/globalisation-is-slowly-dying-2016-7

Answer (score 1):

It does not mean the same thing.

> This is sapping energy from deals such as...

is not the same as

> Deals such as ... are sapping energy

There is a distinct word in the original sentence, "from".